# Is there SEO conflict if making identical posts on Medium and on a standalone website?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I’m writing a series of blog posts and I’m finding a little bit of a conundrum. I want the audience that can be manufactured on Medium but I also want the SEO that comes from long form text on my website.

Is there any type of SEO conflict that would arise from putting the exact same posts on both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the canonical link on your article to be your website, so that any SEO benefits will be redirected there. The only caveat it seems, is that you need to use Medium's import tools.

Here is a page from Medium talking about it.

https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/217991468-Duplicate-Content-and-SEO

Comment: Thanks! It looks like Medium has done a good job of handling the conflict.